# Перенаправление на index.php через .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

У меня сайт типа LP, при кликах  по ссылки в меню, скрол прокручиается до соответсвующего блока.
А URL-ы в выглядят так: http://site/city/interiors . Делал url-ы с помощью : history.pushState . Т.е. все клики в меню сохраняються в истории браузера.

Мне нужно сделать так чтобы при переходе из истории броузера запускалась индексная страница сайта index.php

Я пытался сделать так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Но в этом случае, вроде index.php срабатывает, но не подгружаются css стили, изображения, видео - в общем сайт не работает.

Потом попробовал так:

```
AddType "text/html; charset=utf-8" .htm .html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
PHP_VALUE default_charset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (en|ru) [NC]
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-z_-]+)/([a-zA-z_-]+)$      index.php?city=$1&block=$2
```

Но это не работает, запуска index.php не происходит : Error 404
Подскажите, как это исправить?

Еще один важный момент: если url: http://site/admin ,То перенаправляться на index.php, который в корне сайта, происходить не должно.

Answer (score 1):

> Я пытался сделать так:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
> ```
>
> Но в этом случае, вроде index.php срабатывает, но не подгружаются css
>   стили, изображения, видео - в общем сайт не работает.

А css стили не подгружаются так-как они тоже перенаправляются в index.php

Вам нужно сделать правило и для стилей, примерно так:

```
RewriteRule ^/css/(.*).css$ css/$1.css [L,QSA]
```

Причем поместить его выше, чем общее правило.

Comment: получается, что это  правило мне нужно прописывать для каждого css и js файла  ?

Comment: Почему то не срабатывает. Подскажите, а почему не срабатывает второй описанный мной вариант? Для меня было бы отлично, если бы он сработал т.к. я, в таком случае, смог бы обработать GET параметры при загрузке сайта из истории браузера

Comment: Используя ваш совет у меня выходит так:
если url изначально был "http://domain/city/interiors 
то при переходе по нему получается:
"http://domain/city/css/jquery.ui.slider.css"

Comment: А если оставить только 1 параметр после домена, то все работает, например: http://domain.ru/city

Comment: Это правило сработает только если начинается на /css/ и заканчивается на .css адрес. Т.е. для domain/city/interiors будет перенаправление в index.php?city/interiors.

Для js можно написать аналогично RewriteRule ^/js/(.*).js$ js/$1.js [L,QSA]

По поводу того, почему не срабатывает Ваш второй вариант я ничего не могу сказать.

Answer (score 0):

А что мешает прямо в index.php прописать readfile для CSS и прочих файлов? Лично я так и делаю, по-моему это красиво и логично. Всё таки htaccess это файл конфигурации Apache, а не само веб-приложение. К тому же на php очень удобно прописать все необходимые http заголовки :)

Comment: Если б я знал как это правильно сделать... но я не джедай :(

Comment: @amijin Тогда советую взять готовое решение, джумлу какую нибудь :)